# Display input value with suffix in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have an issue that I should display measurment units after a value in input. The problem is that standard `Bootstrap`'s way to create a span is overkill here, because it requires too many space for it. For example:

```
<div class="input-group margin-bottom">
    <span class="input-group-addon input-source-observer"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-fw"></i></span>
    <span class="input-group-addon input-source-observer" style="text-align: right">Persist deleted items for</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-parsley-trigger="change" placeholder="1" initial-value="1" value="7" style="text-align: right">
    <span class="input-group-addon input-source-observer">days</span>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="restoreInput(event)" value="Recover">
    </span>
</div>
```

[image]

Here it looks fine enough, but in other places it looks really ugly. I want something like [image]

How can I do it with HTML5+CSS3 or/and bootstrap features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating a new class you can adjust the properties of your `input` and `input-group-addon`:

The HTML:

```
<div class="input-group margin-bottom">
    <span class="input-group-addon input-source-observer"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></span>
    <span class="input-group-addon input-source-observer" style="text-align: right">Persist deleted items for</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control addon-inline" data-parsley-trigger="change" placeholder="1" initial-value="1" value="7" style="text-align: right">
    <span class="input-group-addon addon-inline input-source-observer">days</span>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="restoreInput(event)" value="Recover">
    </span>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.input-group-addon.addon-inline {
    background: #fff;
    color: #999;
    border-left: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.input-group .form-control.addon-inline {
    border-right: none;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

The Results:

http://www.bootply.com/BOTmrMi4jV